# How to count number of files in a directory using PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications

How to count the number of files in a directory using PHP?

Please answer for the following things:

**1. Recursive Search**: The directory (which is being searched) might be having several other directories and files.

**2. Non-Recursive Search**: All the directories should be ignored which are inside the directory that is being searched. Only files to be considered.

I am having the following code, but looking for a better solution.

```
<?php

     $files = array();
     $dir = opendir('./items/2/l');
     while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
     {
          if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && !is_dir($file))
          {
               $files[] = $file;
          }
     }
     closedir($dir);
     //sort($files);
     $nooffiles = count($files);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've attempted and can't get working?

Comment: What did you try so far>

Comment: @Garrett, Brandon: edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

non-recrusive:

```
$dir = opendir('dir/');
$i = 0;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))){
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..') and !is_dir($file)) $i++;
}

echo "There were $i files";
```

---

recrusive:

```
function crawl($dir){

    $dir = opendir($dir);
    $i = 0;
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)){
            if (is_dir($file) and !in_array($file, array('.', '..'))){

            $i += crawl($file);
        }else{
            $i++;
        }

    }
    return $i;
}
$i = crawl('dir/');
echo "There were $i files";
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursive:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
$count = 0;
while($it->next()) $count++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the mentioned ways for **"Non-Recursive Search"** work, though it can be shortened using PHP's ***glob*** filesystem function.

It basically finds pathnames matching a pattern and thus can be used as:

```
$count = 0;
foreach (glob('path\to\dir\*.*') as $file) {
    $count++;
}
```

The asterisk before the dot denotes the filename, and the one after denotes the file extension. Thus, its use can further be extended to counting files with specific filenames, specific extensions or both.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful for you:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

But, i think, there is no other good solutions.

Comment: look at my answer, I think it's fine solution

Comment: Yep, good answer) but it is the same that @iSumitG posted except that he collecting all files first.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:
(might need to add some checks for '/' for the $dir.$file concatenation)

```
$files = array();
$dir = './items/2/l';

countFiles($dir, $files); // Recursive
countFiles($dir, $files, false); // Not recursive;

var_dump(count($files));

function countFiles($directory, &$fileArray, $recursive = true){
    $currDir = opendir($directory);    
    while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
    {
        if(is_dir($file) && $recursive){
            countFiles($directory.$fileArray, $saveArray);
        }
        else if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && !is_dir($file))
        {
            $fileArray[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work ;) 1. recrusive and not recrusive is same 2. filearray is not returned :p

Answer (score 0):

Rather than posting code for you, I would provide the outline of what you should do as you seem to have the basic code already.

Place your code in a function. Have two parameters `($path, $recursive = FALSE)` and within your code, separate the `is_dir()` and if that's true and the recursive flag is true, then pass the new path (path to the current file) back to the function (self reference).

Hope this helps you learn, rather than copy paste :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Recursive:**

```
function count_files($path) {

// (Ensure that the path contains an ending slash)

$file_count = 0;

$dir_handle = opendir($path);

if (!$dir_handle) return -1;

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

    if (is_dir($path . $file)){      
        $file_count += count_files($path . $file . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
    else {
        $file_count++; // increase file count
    }
}

closedir($dir_handle);

return $file_count;
```

}

**Non-Recursive**:

```
$directory = ".. path/";
if (glob($directory . "*.") != false)
{
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*."));
 echo $filecount;
}
else
{

 echo 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Courtesy of [Russell Dias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322129/russell-dias)

You can use the [SPL `DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to do this in a non-recursive (or with a [recursive iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) in a recursive) fashion:

```
iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator($directory));
```

It's good to note that this will not just count regular files, but also directories, dot files and symbolic links. For regular files *only*, you can use:

```
$directory = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
$count = 0;
foreach($directory as $file ){ $count += ($file->isFile()) ? 1 : 0;}
```

PHP 5.4.0 also offers:

```
iterator_count(new CallbackFilterIterator($directory, function($current) { return $current->isFile(); }));
```

Comment: @salathe: That source is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = opendir('dir/');
$i = 0;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))){
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..' ))and (!is_dir($file)))
    $i++;
}

echo "There were $i files";
```